# Runtime Error with Recursion Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was trying to come up with a piece of code that sums every possible combination of the given list.

```
class Answer:
    possible = False
    def addAll(self, added, rest, answer):
        if self.possible or added == answer:
            self.possible = True
        elif added < answer:
            for i in range(0, len(rest)):
                temp_rest= rest.copy()
                temp_rest.pop(i)
                self.addAll(added + rest[i], temp_rest, answer)        

n = int(input())
a = Answer()
for rep in range(0, n):
    note,cash = list(map(int,input().split()))
    notelist = []
    a.possible = False
    for x in range(0,note):
        notelist.append(int(input())) #insert tuple
    a.addAll(0,notelist, cash)
    if a.possible:
        print("Yes")
    else: print("No")
```

I think this is a messy code, but nevertheless it works fine as I try it myself.
However, it seems that even after printing all the answers ("Yes" and "No")
program does not finish. I checked that by adding the code `exit()` at the end, and then it prompts that the program is still running.

Probably because of this, CodeChef problem http://www.codechef.com/problems/MARCHA1 gives me NZEC runtime error. Anyway to polish this piece of code? (I DON'T want to just use permutation function in python)

Comment: Can I offer a much simpler version (without permutation functions)?

Comment: What is the point of your class? It has one class attribute, no instance attributes and a single instance method - a standalone function would make more sense.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it prompts that the program is still running"? What is *it*?

Comment: @NPE I meant the code "exit()" at the end of the program, if appended

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes if achievable, i would like to. But this code basically has no base case, or a returning point and it attempts every possible combination even when it finds a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def all_sums(x):
    s = set()
    all_sums_worker(x, s, 0)
    return s

def all_sums_worker(x, s, acc):
    if len(x) == 0:
        s.add(acc)
    else:
        all_sums_worker(x[1:], s, acc + x[0])
        all_sums_worker(x[1:], s, acc)

# the function all_sums(l) returns all possible sums of l
```

Comment: Ah, much better. Is there a way to stop as soon as one possible solution is found?

Comment: Huh? Your question is not clear. If you want one solution, just return the first element of the list.

Comment: all_sums() is only called once, the one that works recursively is the worker. the worker doesn't return anything, but updates a set() object.